# auto refreshing content of div with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json, coldfusion, cfquery

I have a div that does a database query and populates the div with content.

I want to be able to refresh the div every x seconds so it displays any new content.

```
<div id="chatText" class="chatText">

<cfquery name="GetChatConversation" datasource="#request.FlintHost#" dbtype="ODBC">
    SELECT  *
    FROM        tbl_ChatConversation
    WHERE   int_ChatID = #url.int_ChatID#
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="GetChatConversation">
    #str_Name# :#str_Content#<br />
</cfoutput>
</div>
```

I have the following code that refreshes the div but inserts the whole page into the div rather then just refreshing the content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval("my_function();",5000); 
function my_function()
    {
  $('#chatText').load('');
}
</script>
```

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: socket.io . Have a look

Answer (score 1):

I would put the code you want to appear in the div into a separate file (how you do this is up to you).  I've used PHP for this test it does work.

Then for your page and javascript:

```
<div id="chatText" class="chatText"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        setInterval("my_function();",5000); 
        function my_function() {
            $('#chatText').load('link to the external file');
        }
    </script>
```

I called my code from a separate .js file like this:

```
$(function(){

    setInterval("LoadDB();",3000); 

});

function LoadDB(){
    $('#chatText').load('db_load.php');
}
```

This just then refreshed my DIV.  Another approach is you could use some ajax method, but the above approach should work.

Comment: The code mentioned in the first sentence has to include the query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have 2 separate files. The file that contains the chat and the file that generates the content for the chat. You can then load the contents by either loading the chat for the first time or reloading the data using the setTimeout function in a recursive manner to keep refreshing the file every 5000ms.

This is a quick and dirty way of doing it. I would suggest getting your data using JSON and having a better way of displaying your data like using datatables.

File1.cfm

```
<div id="chat">
</div>
<script>
    var loadChat = function(){
        $("#chat").load(file2.cfm);
    }
    var refreshChat = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            loadChat();
            refreshChat();
        ,5000);
    }
    $(document).on('ready',function(){
        loadChat();
        refreshChat();
    });
</script>
```

And file 2 has your content

file2.cfm

```
<cfquery name="GetChatConversation" datasource="#request.FlintHost#" dbtype="ODBC">
    SELECT  *
    FROM        tbl_ChatConversation
    WHERE   int_ChatID = #url.int_ChatID#
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="GetChatConversation">
     #str_Name# :#str_Content#<br />
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) removes the need for your recursive `setTimeout` calls.